# Limpiar datos de formulario después de hacer un POST con AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

Hola tengo un formulario que envío por medio de AJAX. Cuando  envía el POST a PHP, este hace una consulta a una tabla para verificar si existe un registro similar, si existe imprimo un `echo "OK";` y se registra, pero si no existe  imprimo un `No existe` y no se registra.

Todo eso funciona bien, ahora quiero que cuando haga el POST y registre se limpie el formulario, pero si algo anda mal (por ejemplo que no exista un registro igual en la bd) que no se borren los datos del formulario.

He colocado `this.reset()` dentro de `success(){}` pero eso me limpia el formulario independientemente si estaban bien los datos o no

Este es el post:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'suscribe.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                $( '#resultado' ).html(response);
                if(response=="OK") {                                                                     
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        /*Aquí he colocado this.reset() pero igual me resetea los campos si algo anda mal*/
    });
});
```

Gracias por cualquier aporte.

Comment: Pues según el comentario en el código, `this.reset` no está dentro de la función `success`

Comment: Has utilizado **console.log()** para verificar si estas obteniendo la respuesta deseada??, puede ser que este fallando la consulta por eso no ingresa cuando response es igual a "OK", primero comprueba la salida de response, y como dice @César this.reset() esta fuera del reponse, incluso esta fuera del ajax.

Answer (score 3):

A lo que veo, en tu código pusiste el `this.reset()` fuera del success, incluso fuera de tu ajax, coloca el `this.reset()` dentro de tu condición `if(response=="OK")`:

```
success: function (response) {
  $( '#resultado' ).html(response);

if(response=="OK")
      {
         this.reset();
         return true;

      }
      else
      {
         return false;

      }
   }
```

saludos, SUERTE

Comment: Independiente si esta mal colocado o no, eso que dices ya lo he intentado pero no me resetea nada, si lo coloco ahí donde no es correcto si me limpia el formulario pero lo limpia incluso cuando he tenido un error y no registra. He allí mi problema y duda.

Answer (score 2):

En el caso que planteas, `this` (usado dentro de la opción success) se refiere al objeto de la solicitud ajax, no al elemento que activó la solicitud.

Si quieres usar `this` para referirte al formulario en el callback, debes agregarlo en la opción context de `$.ajax()` :

```
$.ajax({
  // las demás opciones de configuración ...
  context: this,
  success: function(response) {
     // aquí `this` se referirá a lo que esté en `context`
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         success: function (response) {
                $( '#resultado' ).html(response);

                if(response=="OK") {                                                                     
                    return true;
               $('#form')[0].reset(); //aqui esta la solucionn     <----------- 
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        /*Aquí he colocado this.reset() pero igual me resetea los campos si algo anda mal*/
    });
});
```

Comment: Ivan! que bien que aporta, sería buen idea agregar una explicación de tu respuesta, no únicamente código!, saludos.

Comment: Gracias claro que solo que con el solo código esta la explicación puesto que agregue un comentario en el indicando cual es la solución y en que posición debe de estar

Comment: tratare de ser mas claro la próxima vez

Comment: ¿El `reset` no debería ser dependiente si el resultado sale "OK"? ¿Lo tienes en el lugar correcto? Yo creo que el comentario en el código es suficiente si la respuesta soluciona el problema, pero yo entendí que el OP solamente quiere limpiar el formulario si la solicitud funciona **y** el resultado es "OK".

Answer (score -1):

Hola x4mp73r creo que entiendo lo que quieres lograr:

Espero te sea útil..esta es una manera de recibir varias respuestas a través de ajax:

```
   success: function (response) {

        res = response.split('||'); //separas los datos en un array

        $( '#resultado' ).html(res[1]); //res[1] será el response que te traías

        if(res[0]==1) { //res[0] será "OK" si todo fue registrado con éxito
             this.reset();                                             
        }
   }
```

Entonces en el PHP que maneja el registro, debes imprimir cuando este haya sido exitoso, tus "response" concatenados con un separador...

```
<?php
 ...
 if($existe === true) //puedes hacer el registro acá en caso de que exista un registro similar
     echo 1.'||'.'OK'; //1 si existe y OK si registra
 else
     echo 0.'||'.'No existe' //respuesta si no existe
```

Si todavía puedo ayudarte avísame!.

Comment: Hola @AdrianVignolo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Leyendo la respuesta no entiendo cómo está relacionada específicamente a la pregunta, o parecería que se copio y pego un fragmento de otro código. En ningún lugar de la pregunta se busca hacer un split en `||`, ni ver si la respuesta es 1. La idea es agregar respuestas de calidad que estén dirigidas específicamente a la pregunta. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]

Comment: Con todo respeto Sr. Mariano,
Mi respuesta fue redactada totalmente desde mi conocimiento y experiencia.
Tal vez tu punto de vista sobre la pregunta que Armando Ramirez hizo hace 10 meses esta equivocado... debes considerarlo y no opinar sobre la buena intención de los nuevos usuarios que tratan de aportar algo a este foro que a muchos le ha resuelto las dudas.

Comment: Corrijo -> x4mp73r